# Save Kendo Pagable User Input To Persist Grid State

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, pageable

I'm having a problem with Kendo `.Pagable`. We have a webapplication that displays entries in a **grid**. The user can choose between **25, 50, 100, 200** entries per site. But whenever the user enters the entry edit page and goes back to the overview page it gets reset to **25 entries per page**.

I could not find out how to persist the state (let's say 100 entries per page) for the grid on reload. Can you help me out?

Here the code snippet

```
GRID.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .PageSize(25)
          .Model(m => { m.Id(a => a.Id); })
          .Read(read => read
              .Action("Read", "Overview")
              .Data("additionalGridData"))
          .Sort(x => x.Add(y => y.Id))
      )
      .AutoBind(false)
      .Filterable()
      .Sortable(c=>c.SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn).AllowUnsort(true).ShowIndexes(true).Enabled(true))
      .Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(new[] {25, 50, 100, 200}))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Save grid options in `localStorage` on edit or on `window.onbeforeunload` then load options and set it on grid. This is an example with jQuery, but it is the same approach for other languages.

```
//save
let options = $('#grid').getKendoGrid().getOptions();
localStorage['grid-options'] = kendo.stringify(options);

//load
let options = localStorage['grid-options'];
let optionsObject = JSON.parse(options);
$('#grid').getKendoGrid().setOptions(optionsObject);
```

This will save page size, current page, and other things.

Comment: Seems like dataSource.PageSize overwrites options on load of the grid. But if not set the default size is 10...which is not an pageable option